# http_post_data adding extra characters in response

Tags: php, http, post

Hey Guys I am getting some extra characters like '5ae' and '45c' interspersed along with valid data when using http_post_data.  The data I am sending is XML and so is the response.  The response contains these weird characters thats making the XML invalid.  If I use fsockopen I do not have this issue.  Would really like some input on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not giving much details, but *(quite a wild guess, but this reminds me of that)* this could related to **[Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)** *(quoting)* :

> If a Transfer-Encoding header with a
>   value of chunked is specified in an
>   HTTP message, the body of the message
>   is made of an unspecified number of
>   chunks ending with a last, zero-sized,
>   chunk.
>
> Each non-empty chunk starts with the
>   number of octets of the data it embeds
>   *(size written in hexadecimal)* followed by a CRLF *(carriage return
>   and line feed)*, and the data itself.

The `5ae` and `45c` you're getting in your data could correspond to the size of each chunk.

If you are trying to send HTTP requests *by hand*, that might no be such a good idea : HTTP is not such an easy protocol, and you should use already-existing libraries that will deal with those kind of troubles for you.

For instance, you could take a look at [curl](http://fr.php.net/curl) -- see [`curl_setopt`](http://fr.php.net/curl_setopt) for the impressive list of possible options.

Edit : I realize that [`http_post_data`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-data.php) is a function provided by the [PECL http extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php).

There's a function that might interest you, in that library, to decode chunked data : [`http_chunked_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-chunked-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a result of Chucked Transfer Encoding.
We may observe this behavior in fiddler by unchecking the 'Chunked Transfer-Encoding' in the Transformer tab of response pane.